# How to tell the folder / path that will save the created file

Tags: php

I'm creating files generated by PHP everything is ok but I wanted to put the generated files in a folder above, I made some attempts but without success, my folder to storage the generated files is diagramasBPMN.

PHP savel.php

```
<?php 
  file_put_contents(/diagramasBPMN/$_POST['idDiagrama'], $_POST['diagramaXml']);

  die('file has been saved');
?>
```

JS

```
$.post('/../../savel.php', { diagramaXml: xml, idDiagrama: diagramaID, function(data) { 
            // output response to console
            console.log('sucess'); 

            }
          });
```

Comment: At least use [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to prevent path injection.

Comment: where i add, thanks